# Casting object to type without generics

Tags: c#, exception

```
public class ErrorCode
{
    public int HttpStatus { get; private set; }
    public string JsonErrorCode { get; private set; }
    public Type ExceptionT { get; private set; }

    public ErrorCode(string pJsonErrorCode, int pHttpStatus, Type pExceptionType)
    {
        this.HttpStatus = pHttpStatus;
        this.JsonErrorCode = pJsonErrorCode;
    }

    public void ThrowException(string pMsg)
    {
        throw Activator.CreateInstance(ExceptionT, pMsg);
    }
}
```

So, as you can see i am trying to create an instance of the given type. I cannot use Generics. because i have a dictionary that creates a pool of error codes.

```
Protocol.ErrorCodes.Add
(
    ErrorCodeType.ElementClickIntercepted,
    new ErrorCode
    (
        "element click intercepted", 
        400, 
        typeof(ElementClickInterceptedException)
    )
);
```

The above code doesn't work since the type being created is of type object and does not derive from system.exception

The above code won't work with generics since the dictionary needs to understand what is being built. I am not sure what to do here. my dictionary has about 50 different exceptions. Thoughts?

Comment: You could use an interface, and use generics in the actual implementations of the interface... then your dictionary could be defined as `Dictionary<ErrorCodeType, IErrorCode>` (where `IErrorCode` is an interface)

Answer (score 2):

**You need to cast the instance created to Exception**

```
public class ErrorCode
{
  public int HttpStatus { get; private set; }
  public string JsonErrorCode { get; private set; }
  public Type ExceptionT { get; private set; }

  public ErrorCode(string pJsonErrorCode, int pHttpStatus, Type pExceptionType)
  {
    this.HttpStatus = pHttpStatus;
    this.JsonErrorCode = pJsonErrorCode;
    this.ExceptionT = pExceptionType;
  }

  public void ThrowException(string pMsg)
  {
    throw (Exception)Activator.CreateInstance(ExceptionT, pMsg);
  }
}
```

You can replace `Exception` by `ElementClickInterceptedException` or anything needed.

**Test**

```
var error = new ErrorCode("test", 1, typeof(ArgumentException));
try
{
  error.ThrowException("error");
}
catch ( Exception ex )
{
  Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
}
```

[Fiddle Snippet](https://dotnetfiddle.net/6BNcFt)

**Output**

```
error
```

Comment: This does not work because it will cast it as an exception and not a ElementClickInterceptedException

Comment: So you can use ElementClickInterceptedException instead if it inherits from some Exception.

Comment: yes but the object doesn't know about ElementClickInterceptedException. The question states that i have a ton of exceptions to deal with.

Comment: At first glance, there is no solution to this thing since the throw keyword requires an instance of exception type and you can not dynamicaly cast the CreateInstance result, from what I know, unless you use generics.

Answer (score 1):

> I cannot use Generics. because i have a dictionary that creates a pool of error codes.

Yes, you really can, and it is the right solution. You just need to declare a base interface for your lookup dictionary.

```
public interface IErrorCode
{
    int HttpStatus { get; }
    string JsonErrorCode { get; }
    void ThrowException(string pMsg);
}

public class ErrorCode<T> : IErrorCode where T : Exception
{
    public int HttpStatus { get; private set; }
    public string JsonErrorCode { get; private set; }

    public ErrorCode(string pJsonErrorCode, int pHttpStatus)
    {
        this.HttpStatus = pHttpStatus;
        this.JsonErrorCode = pJsonErrorCode;
    }

    public void ThrowException(string pMsg)
    {
        var exception = (T)Activator.CreateInstance
        (
            typeof(T), 
            new object[] { pMsg }
        );
        throw exception;
    }
}


//Declare the dictionary with the interface, not the concrete type
Protocol.ErrorCodes = new Dictionary<ErrorCodeType,IErrorCode>();

Protocol.ErrorCodes.Add
(
    ErrorCodeType.ElementClickIntercepted,
    new ErrorCode<ElementClickInterceptedException>
    (
        "element click intercepted", 
        400
    )
);
```

If you need to work with any element in the list, you can use the interface-- you should not have to cast anything.

To get the HTTP status:

```
var status = Protocol.ErrorCodes[key].HttpStatus;
```

To get the Json error code:

```
var errorCode = Protocol.ErrorCodes[key].JsonErrorCode;
```

In general your code should not be depending on concrete instances but on interfaces (per the "D" in [SOLID](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SOLID)).

Comment: This does not work for me, as i have functions returning errorcode objects, where i dont know what interface to give to the generic type. This also casts everything as an exception. So when throwing errors it just throws exceptions instead of ElementClickInterceptedExceptions.

Comment: public static ErrorCode GetErrorCode(ErrorCodeType pType)
        {
            Protocol.ErrorCodes.TryGetValue(pType, out ErrorCode errorCode);
            return errorCode;
        }

Comment: Notice how this function returns an error code based on the key. Well, i very well can't return the value while knowing the key and its exception

Comment: Add `ErrorCode`, and anything else you need, to the common interface.

Comment: this doesn't solve the issue of... well there is no point in adding the interface since you are casting everything as its parent object.

Comment: The pointing of adding to the interface is so that you do not have to cast. I've edited the example to illustrate.